# How to create a correct JPA Many to Many Relationship

Tags: java, database, jpa

I have a "subcategory" table and an "item" table on the database. One item can have many subcategories and one subcategory can have many items.

When using JPA, if I delete a subcategory, it deletes not only the relationship (from the mapping table) but also all the associated items also.

What i need is, deleting a subcategory without deleting the items. But if that subcategory is the only one subcategory associated with an item, the item should be also deleted.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxZM3.jpg

Please check the image

So here, if i delete subcategory1, only Item1 should be deleted with it.(In the current situation it deletes Item2 also)

Here's my code:

part of SubCategory.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sub_category")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"items"})
public class SubCategory extends AuditModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci",
            nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "subCategories", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

part of Item.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Item")
public class Item extends AuditModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci",
            nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private List<SubCategory> subCategories = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

PS: I tried removing cascadeType, but it doesn't work because an item must have at least one subcategory

Comment: Have a look at this one https://thorben-janssen.com/best-practices-for-many-to-many-associations-with-hibernate-and-jpa/